# flutter_webview_plugin: how to open a link in default browser

Tags: flutter, webview

I use `flutter_webview_plugin` and I would like to open a link; not in my webview, but in the browser of the user. When I use `StreamSubscription` with `String`, the app listens only to the url from the app, like when I use `FlutterWebViewPlugin().reloadUrl` or `.launchUrl`.

Comment: did you give [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) a try ?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, because I didn't find a way to listen urls inside of my webview...

Comment: There is an example on [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#launch-webview-fullscreen-with-flutter-navigation) page, showing:
`flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {});`

Comment: Thanks all for your answers ! @TesteurManiak, I try but it only works for url changed by `flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl` or `flutterWebviewPlugin.launchUrl`, and it's not why I'm looking for...

Comment: Did you try closing your webView when the url change and launching url_launcher with it ?

Comment: I'll try, thanks for your support !

Comment: Update: It's works ! But not how I want. Indeed, the url is launch in the browser, but launch too in my webview... Anyone have an idea to solve this ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you share some of your code? It would be easier to understand what is wrong

Comment: I find a solution: I made a `reloadUrl` with `FlutterWebviewPlugin`, and I use the history to get the url that I want to reload. Thanks to this, when I click on a link, it opens a new tab, and keep the previous page. Thanks all for your help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package concurrently with the [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) to get your desired effect.

Basically with the webview, you can use the parameter `invalidUrlRegex` in either `launch` or the `WebviewScaffold` to setup URLs not allowed to be opened inside your webview.

eg: below blocks any links that dont have the host google or stackoverflow.

```
invalidUrlRegex: r'^(?!https:\/{2}www\.google\.com|https:\/{2}stackoverflow\.com).*$'
```

Then have an `onStateChanged` listener on the webview, this will cause any blocked URLs to result in a `WebViewState.abortLoad` state.

```
FlutterWebviewPlugin().onStateChanged.listen(onStateChanged);    

onStateChanged(WebViewStateChanged change) {
  if (change.type == WebViewState.abortLoad) {
    canLaunch(change.url).then((val) => val ? launch(change.url) : null);
  }
}
```

The above will use the url_launcher to launch the URL in the user's preferred browser.

This is by far the best approach that I was able to come up within our application.